# Guessing Game logic (binary search)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Working on a problem in which I take a user's input (1-10) and guess what number they are thinking of using binary search, and update the range dependent on their answer (e.g. if it is greater than 5, I update the lowerLimit to 6) but am having trouble with the logic.

I use the middle cell as reference by adding 1 to the middle cell when they say it is greater than it, but I believe this is where I get confused. I can't figure out how to intertwine my if/else statement to update the number correctly.

Main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test your program here
        GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame();
        game.play(1,10);
       
    }    
}
```

GuessingGame method (play method is the one I'm working with):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GuessingGame {
    
    private Scanner reader;
    

    public GuessingGame() {
        // use only this scanner, othervise the tests do not work
        this.reader = new Scanner(System.in);
       
             
    }

    public void play(int LL, int UL) {
       
       instructions(LL, UL);
       int limit = howManyTimesHalvable(UL - LL);
       int finalNumber = 0;
       int midPoint = average(LL, UL);
       
       int avgLL;
       int avgUL;
       
       
       
        
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
            
            
            if(isGreaterThan(midPoint)){
                midPoint++;
                LL = midPoint;
                
                midPoint = average(UL,LL);
                finalNumber = LL;
            }else{
                midPoint--;
                UL = midPoint;
                
                midPoint = average(UL,LL);
                finalNumber = LL;
               
             
            }
           
            
            if(UL == LL){
                break;
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println("Your number is : " + finalNumber);
     }
       
        
        
        
        

        

    

   public boolean isGreaterThan(int value){
       
       System.out.println("Is your number greater than " + value + "?");
       return reader.nextLine().equals("y");
   }
   
   public int average(int firstNumber, int secondNumber){
       int total =  firstNumber + secondNumber ; 
       return total / 2;
   }

    public void instructions(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
        int maxQuestions = howManyTimesHalvable(upperLimit - lowerLimit);

        System.out.println("Think of a number between " + lowerLimit + "..." + upperLimit + ".");

        System.out.println("I promise you that I can guess the number you are thinking with " + maxQuestions + " questions.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Next I'll present you a series of questions. Answer them honestly.");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    // a helper method:
    public static int howManyTimesHalvable(int number) {
        // we create a base two logarithm  of the given value

        // Below we swap the base number to base two logarithms!
        return (int) (Math.log(number) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to update the ranges accordingly, when a user says that the number that they've guessed is higher or lower than what is shown to them.

Edit, example entries:

Looking for number 9,

```
LL: 1 
UL: 10
limit:4 
finalNumber:0 
midPoint:5 
i: 0

Is your number greater than 5?
y

LL: 6
UL: 10
limit:4 
finalNumber:6
midPoint:8
i: 1

Is your number greater than 8?

LL: 9
UL: 10
limit:4 
finalNumber:9
midPoint:9
i: 2

Is your number greater than 9?
n


LL: 9
UL: 8
limit:4 
finalNumber:9
midPoint:8
i: 3

Is your number greater than 8?
y

Your number is : 9
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with the debugger to look at how it behaves? Alternatively, perhaps printing out the changes to midPoint, LL and UL at each step would help.

Comment: @tgdavies I can make that an edit for 3 entries, let me get that.

Comment: @tgdavies hope that gives more clarity.

Comment: That's a working example. What is a number that it fails for?

Comment: @tgdavies 2 would be an example. If I say 'n' for 'is your number greater than 2' it always assumes the number guessed is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have midPoint--;
Since you are asking the question as "is Grater than"? Your new upper limit should be midpoint if the answer is no.

Comment: Hear me out, following that logic, wouldn't that just leave the upperLimit at 5, since 1 + 10 / 2 = 5? I am trying to change the range to (1,4) if it is not greater than 5.

Comment: If the value is not grater than 5, then your range should be 1 - 5, right?

Comment: the current number (5) and anything greater would be omitted, if it is not greater than 5.

Comment: The question you are asking is, "Is Grater than 5", If the answer is, "No," then everything above 5 will be gone. In this case, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 are not valid anymore. So, you will be left with 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, right? So, your new range should be (1-5), not (1-4) unless I am missing something here. Please help me if I am wrong.

Comment: And 5 will be gone too. The logic there is that the number we’re looking for cannot be equal to 5 or greater, only leaving 1-4.

Comment: Hey, I worked through it again and it turns out you were right after all! Why is it that we add to the LowerLimit, but not minus from the UpperLimit? Truly confusing to me!